# Run a function after all API calls are finished inside a for loop React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a function in my react application that is pretty much a for loop which loops through a state array and passes each id into the url call as a parameter. I want all those promises to be resolved before dynamically generating a button for the user to click on to get to the next page. Right now the button is generated on a setTimeout which is really bad design and still sometimes does not work properly.

Here's the function:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to use a `Promise.all()` to execute the logic only once all promises have been resolved.

Example (from [here](https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5)):

```
// These two promises run sequentially
let characterResponse = await fetch('http://swapi.co/api/people/2/')
let characterResponseJson = await characterResponse.json()

// These promises run in parallel and the code only continues once "films" is ready
let films = await Promise.all(
  characterResponseJson.films.map(async filmUrl => {
    let filmResponse = await fetch(filmUrl)
    return filmResponse.json()
  })
)

console.log(films)
```

Comment: Hi Telmo, kinda a newbee when it comes to dealing with promises and whatnot. Can you maybe give me more guidance of how this will work in my code? I added 2 images of the function.

Comment: Can you make a minimum reproducible example? With that function itself I don't really have enough context to help you code-wise.